# Inconsistent Piwik response and no tracking

Tags: analytics, matomo

I am setting up Piwik on an IIS server. I have my website set up to properly load the Piwik tracking JS. I have the site configured in Piwik.

When I load the page in either IE or Safari, I get a 400 from Piwik, which is expected *if* the request is missing the tracking parameters, but my request isn't. It has `siteid` and the other parameters as GET query string parameters.

The same request from Chrome returns a 204, which is also expected, but the visit is not logged in Piwik.

I cannot find where I may have Piwik misconfigured, and I cannot figure out why IE/Safari are getting 400 when Chrome gets a 204.

What should I look at for fixing my Piwik installation to log the requests and not send back a 400 to IE/Safari?

I am using Piwik v2.13.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you also passing `&rec=1` parameter? To debug it further please enable tracker debug mode in config.ini.php:

`[Tracker]
debug=1`

With such configuration `piwik.php` resource should print relevant debug info.

Comment: THANK YOU! It was an because of [this issue](https://github.com/piwik/piwik/issues/6642). I am using MySQL 5.7 and one of the columns wasn't created in the DB. Added the column and everything works. The debug let me find the SQL error.